# Display information and take user input in alert box - heading, select options, confirm, cancel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am calling an alert box but the requirement is that I've to display some information in that box and take a little bit of input from user.

I have a heading, select options to get the reason from user and confirm button and a delete button.

Here are these elements

```html
<div style="width:50%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border:1px solid;padding:20px">
    <h4 style="margin-top:0px">Alert</h4>
    <p>
        Please select a reason from the list. <i>(required)</i>
    </p>
    <select style="width:100%">
        <option></option>
        <option>Reason one</option>
        <option>Reason two</option>
        <option>Reason three</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;
    <div style="float:right;padding-top:10px">
        <button type="button">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to put this much information in alert box? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions, especially examples about good and bad titles: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - everything else looks good.

Comment: alert box? if you mean standard javascript `window.alert` - then, no. If you mean some sort of alert box that comes in some javascript library, then please add what library you are using

Comment: I do not see any javascript, that calls the alert function. Or do you mean with `alert box` an overlay?

Comment: [Perhaps JQuery dialog can help you](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: There is no alert box here. Actually this is the information that I want to show in alert box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, there's no support to display that much information in alert box. However, you can use bootstrap modal for that purpose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="1.9.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Call Alert Box
    </button>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Alert</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please select a reason from the list. <i>(required)</i></p>
            <select style="width:100%">
              <option></option>
              <option>Reason one</option>
              <option>Reason two</option>
              <option>Reason three</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do your requirements with an javascript alert box. Only javascript default function to get input is [prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) (scroll down to prompt):

```
window.prompt("sometext","defaultText");
```

Your approach to display it in a lightbox/overlay is good. You could lay it over your website content.

Like @Tikkes mentioned in your question comments, [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) might help you.